# how to set Custom Progress bar in center?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I Created Sample program for custom progress bar. it is working but the problem i'm facing is that the progress bar is not set in the middle of the screen.

I have to show list's View items before that i want to show the Progress bar.

Here my complete code is as follow :-

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/AVLoadingIndicatorView.Large"
        app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
        android:id="@+id/avi"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/visitor_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
    private AVLoadingIndicatorView avi;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_rorder, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Order");
        String indicator=getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("indicator");
        avi= (AVLoadingIndicatorView)view.findViewById(R.id.avi);
        avi.setIndicator(indicator);

        new DownloadJSON().execute();
        return view;
    }
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            avi.show();
//            avi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            /*
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

            mProgressDialog.show();
*/

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            try {
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
//            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                avi.hide();
        }
    }    

}
```

Like This I tried But it is not working please help me out from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `RelativeLayout` as a parent of the `ListView` and `AVLoadingIndicatorView`, and settings the `layout_centerInParent` attribute of `AVLoadingIndicatorView` to true  :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#000"
            style="@style/AVLoadingIndicatorView.Large"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
            android:id="@+id/avi"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/visitor_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply You can use the Progress Dialog. Example is given below

```
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Please  Wait ", true, false);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

        }
```